# JavaFx :How to recover last modifications of Fxml file?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, netbeans-8, scenebuilder, recover

I'm currently working on javaFx project using **scene builder** & **Netbeans**.I removed tabPane with all nodes from my fxml file and i closed  sceneBuilder.I tried to recover last modifications but i could not.Any one have some tricks using scene builder or Netbeans or other way to recover last modifications?

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans, you can try to open the fxml (right click | edit) and then in main menu: View | Editors | History.

But I'm not sure if the history is available if you deleted it in sceneBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to recover is ctrl + z.  If that doesn't work, you have no other choice other than redesigning your layout from scratch.